cs50 week 4 filter less comfortable blur function not working
I have already put the total_red, total_blue etc as float but I don't know why it is still not working for my blur function. Can someone explain to me what is wrong?
void blur(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    // Create a copy of image
    RGBTRIPLE copy[height][width];
    float total_red = 0, total_blue = 0, total_green = 0, count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            for (int k = i - 1; k < i + 2; k++)
            {
                for (int z = j - 1; z < j + 2; z++)
                {
                    if (k >= 0 && z >= 0 && k < height && z < width)
                    {
                        total_red += image[k][z].rgbtRed;
                        total_blue += image[k][z].rgbtBlue;
                        total_green += image[k][z].rgbtGreen;
                        count++;
                    }
                }
            }
            copy[i][j].rgbtRed = round(total_red/count);
            copy[i][j].rgbtBlue = round(total_blue/count);
            copy[i][j].rgbtGreen = round(total_green/count);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            image[i][j] = copy[i][j];
        }
    }
}


Don't tag C++ if the question is about C. And why is count a float??

Can you please clarify on what "not working" entails?

You need to set the total_XXX variables to 0 before each k loop. You're summing the RGB values over the entire image.

Move the variables used for calculating the average colors into the loop, so you're just averaging the pixels around the current one. You're averaging all the pixels processed since the beginning of the function.
void blur(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    // Create a copy of image
    RGBTRIPLE copy[height][width];

    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            float total_red = 0, total_blue = 0, total_green = 0, count = 0;
            for (int k = i - 1; k < i + 2; k++)
            {
                for (int z = j - 1; z < j + 2; z++)
                {
                    if (k >= 0 && z >= 0 && k < height && z < width)
                    {
                        total_red += image[k][z].rgbtRed;
                        total_blue += image[k][z].rgbtBlue;
                        total_green += image[k][z].rgbtGreen;
                        count++;
                    }
                }
            }
            copy[i][j].rgbtRed = round(total_red/count);
            copy[i][j].rgbtBlue = round(total_blue/count);
            copy[i][j].rgbtGreen = round(total_green/count);
        }
    }

    memcpy(image, copy, sizeof copy);
}

You can also use memcpy() to copy the entire array all at once, rather than using another set of loops.

Ohh I understand it now. Thank you!

What to do when someone answers your question
